# New to programming / python. Using "if" and inequalities for the first time

Tags: python-3.7

Here is my problem:

-I need to determine who is the oldest by testing the value of the numbers and then printing out his/her name as follows. I don't really know how to use inequality's and the "if" command properly or if you can even use them together

This is for Python 3.7. I am using Wing IDE 101 6.1... 
I Have tried quite a few variations of these terms with no luck.

if dob1>dob2 print(name1,"is older than",name2,):
     else print(name2,"is older than",name1,)
     else dob1==dob2 print(name1,"and",name2,"are the same age" )

## User Input name and DoB

```
name1=input("Enter your Name:")
dob1=int(input("Enter your date of birth(YYYYMMDD):"))
name2=input("Enter your Name:")
dob2=int(input("Enter your date of birth(YYYYMMDD):"))
```

## Seperate into month/day/year

```
day1=(dob1%100)
month1=(dob1%10000)//100
year1=(dob1)//10000
day2=(dob2%100)
month2=(dob2%10000)//100
year2=(dob2)//10000
```

## Print name and date of birth

```
print(name1,"was born on",str(day1)+"/"+str(month1)+"/"+str(year1))
print(name2,"was born on",str(day2)+"/"+str(month2)+"/"+str(year2))
```

## Compare who is older then print name is older than other name

```
if dob1>dob2 print(name1,"is older than",name2,):
   else print(name2,"is older than",name1,)
   else dob1==dob2 print(name1,"and",name2,"are the same age" )
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you do condition in Python:

```
if condition1:
    pass
else if condition2:
    pass
else:
    pass
```

Where `pass` is a placeholder you can replace with your code. Order is important. Your code becomes:

```
if dob1>dob2:
    print(name1,"is older than",name2,)
else if dob1==dob2:
    print(name1,"and",name2,"are the same age" )
else:
    print(name2,"is older than",name1,)
```